# How to cache slow resource initialisation from C# Web API REST Server?

Tags: c#, rest, caching, asp.net-web-api

**Context**

I am trying to implement a REST API web service that "wraps" an existing C program.

**Problem / Goal**

Given that the C program has slow initialisation time and high RAM usage when I tell it to open a specific folder (assume this cannot be improved), I am thinking of caching the C handle/object, so the next time a GET request hits the same folder, I can use the existing handle.

**What I've tried**

First declare a static dictionary mapping from folder path to handle:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, IHandle> handles = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IHandle>();
```

In my GET function:

```
IHandle theHandle = handles.GetOrAdd(dir.Name, x => {
    return new Handle(x); //this is the slow and memory-intensive function
});
```

This way, whenever a specific folder has been GET'd before, it will already have a handle ready for me to use.

**Why it's not good**

So now I run the risk of running out of memory if too many folders are cached simultaneously. How might I add a GC-like background process to `TryRemove()` and call `IHandle.Dispose()` on old handles, perhaps in a Least Recently Used or Least Frequently Used policy? Ideally it should start triggering only upon low physical memory available.

I have tried adding the following statement in the GET function, but it seems too hacky and is very limited in function. This way works OK only if I always want handles to expire after 10 seconds, and it does not restart the timer if a subsequent request comes in within 10 seconds.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    if (handles.TryRemove(dir.Name, out var handle2))
        handle2.Dispose();
});
```

**What this question is not**

I don't think caching the output is the solution here. After I return the result of this GET request (it's just the metadata of the folder contents), there might be another GET request for more in-depth data, which requires calling `Handle`'s methods.

I hope my question is clear enough!

Comment: You said response contains just folder metadata? Do the folders (metadata) change often? Why not to cache only the metadata ?

Comment: as stated in last part of my question, there may be a further GET request for more detailed data, so I need to keep the Handle in memory, not just the metadata.

Comment: I read you now. If the detailed request will come is there still the need to keep the handle open?

Comment: There can be any number of subsequent detailed requests. Holding the handle open allows me to respond to these detailed requests very quickly. There is no chance of caching the detailed requests because there are too many different possible outputs. I wish to hold the handle for as long as I can, until physical memory goes low, then I release them, hopefully in LRU / LFU fashion.

Comment: I didn’t noticed your LRU / LFU demand first time. Are you still interested in it? Also I realized your code could be still vulnerable to OutOfMemoryException. That depands on YOUR_TRESHHOLD and biggest file expected ratio and also request manner. Will there be simultaneous requests? How often the request could come? Also I realized there is no need to periodic check for memory level. That could be done on handle load if there is exception on memory level.That will kill two birds with one stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Handles closing on low memory.

```cs
ConcurrentQueue<(string, IHandle)> handles = new ConcurrentQueue<(string, IHandle)>();

void CheckMemory_OptionallyReleaseOldHandles()
{
  var performance = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

  while (performance.NextValue() <= YOUR_TRESHHOLD)
  {
    if (handles.TryDequeue(out ValueTuple<string, IHandle> value))
    {
      value.Item2.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

2. Your Get method.

```cs
IHandle GetHandle()
{
  IHandle theHandle = handles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Item1 == dir.Name).Item2;

  if (theHandle == null)
  {
    theHandle = new Handle(dir.Name);
    handles.Enqueue((dir.Name, theHandle));
  }

  return theHandle;
});
```

3. Your background task.

```cs
void SetupMemoryCheck()
{

  Action<CancellationToken> BeCheckingTheMemory = ct =>
  {

    for(;;)
    {
      if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        break;
      }

      CheckMemory_OptionallyReleaseOldHandles();
      Thread.Sleep(500);
    };
  };

  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
  {
    var tf = new TaskFactory(ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Current);
    tf.StartNew(() => BeCheckingTheMemory(ct));
  });
}
```

I suppose the collection will have little elems so there is no need to dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I did’t catch your LRU/LFU demand first time. Here you can check for some hybrid LRU/LFU cache model.

1. Handles closing on low memory.

```cs
/* 
*  string – handle name,
*  IHandle – the handle,
*  int – hit count,
*/
ConcurrentDictionary<string, (IHandle, int)> handles = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, (IHandle, int)>();

void FreeResources()
{
  if (handles.Count == 0)
  {
    return;
  }

  var performance = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

  while (performance.NextValue() <= YOUR_TRESHHOLD)
  {
    int maxIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(handles.Count / 2.0d);
    KeyValuePair<string, (IHandle, int)> candidate = handles.First();

    for (int index = 1; index < maxIndex; index++)
    {
      KeyValuePair<string, (IHandle, int)> item = handles.ElementAt(index);

      if(item.Value.Item2 < candidate.Value.Item2)
      {
        candidate = item;
      }          
    }

    candidate.Value.Item1.Dispose();
    handles.TryRemove(candidate.Key, out _);
  }
}
```

2. Get method.

```cs
IHandle GetHandle(Dir dir, int handleOpenAttemps = 1)
{
  if(handles.TryGetValue(dir.Name, out (IHandle, int) handle))
  {
    handle.Item2++;
  }
  else
  {

    if(new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes").NextValue() < YOUR_TRESHHOLD)
    {
      FreeResources();
    }

    try
    {
      handle.Item1 = new Handle(dir.Name);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException)
    {

      if (handleOpenAttemps == 2)
      {
        return null;
      }

      FreeResources();
      return GetHandle(dir, handleOpenAttemps++);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      // Your handling.
    }

    handle.Item2 = 1;
    handles.TryAdd(dir.Name, handle);
  }       

  return handle.Item1;
}
```

3. Background task.

```cs
void SetupMemoryCheck()
{

  Action<CancellationToken> BeCheckingTheMemory = ct =>
  {

    for (;;)
    {        
      if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;          

      FreeResources();
      Thread.Sleep(500);        
    }
  };

  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
  {
    new Task(() => BeCheckingTheMemory(ct), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
  });
}
```

If you expect big collection the for loop could be optimised.